# Insert a load and a store instruction before the first instruction of the first basicblock of a function

Tags: llvm

I want to insert a load and a store instruction before the first instruction of the first basicblock of a function (used to simulation the performance overhead of our work). The the LLVM pass is written as following:

```
    Value *One = llvm::ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context),1); 
    for(Function::iterator bb = tmp->begin(); bb != tmp->end(); ++bb        {                                                      
    //for every instruction of the block
    for (BasicBlock::iterator inst = bb->begin(); inst != bb->end(); ++inst){
       if(inst == bb->begin() && bb == tmp->begin()){
           BasicBlock* bp = &*bb;
           Instruction* pinst = &*inst;
           AllocaInst *pa = new AllocaInst(Int32Ty, "buf", pinst);
           StoreInst* newstore = new StoreInst(One, pa, pinst);
           LoadInst* newload = new LoadInst(pa, "loadvalue", pinst);
       }
     }
   }
```

The inserted load and store instructions can be seen in the xx.ll file:

```
    define i32 @fun() #0 {
    entry:
      %buf = alloca i32
      %loadvalue = load i32, i32* %buf
      store i32 %loadvalue, i32* %buf         
      %call = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0))
      ret i32 1
   }
```

However, the inserted instructions disappeared in the target executable file.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

They were probably eliminated by optimization because they don't have any visible effect.  Try marking the load and store as volatile.

In general your algorithm won't work because LLVM expects all of the allocas in a function to be the first instructions.  You should scan through the first basic block and find the first non-alloca instruction and insert new code there, making sure to add allocas first (as you did).